# Python 2.7 Grammar Geek - Lambda in List Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, list-comprehension, grammar

Can you build a minimal valid example of source code which would match to the following [Python 2.7 grammar rules](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Grammar/Grammar)? Is it possible without producing a runtime error?

```
(1) atom:           '[' [listmaker] ']'
(2) listmaker:      test  list_for
(3) list_for:       'for' exprlist 'in' testlist_safe
(4) testlist_safe:  old_test
(5) old_test:       old_lambdef
(6) old_lambdef:    'lambda' [varargslist] ':' old_test
```

The best result I could reach so far is:

```
L = [ fn() for fn in (lambda: x for x in xrange(3)) ]
```

But the problem with my solution is the parentheses around "lambda". Can you build an example without the parentheses? If not, then how would you explain why you cannot build 'in lambda' even if it perfectly matches the grammar rules?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: The definitions of `old_test` and `old_lambdef` are mutually recursive.  I don't think that's right.

Comment: @user2357112 Sure: I'm looking for a python source code which will trigger the described grammar rules from (1) to (6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[x for x in lambda: 1]
```

It's quite straightforward. Of course, this will produce a TypeError at runtime, but the grammar isn't designed to exclude constructs that will produce TypeErrors.

There's no way to do it without an exception at runtime, since an `old_lambdef` always evaluates to a function object, which isn't iterable. There's nowhere in the structure of `old_lambdef` where you could insert something to make Python call the function; Python will attempt to iterate over the function object itself, rather than calling it and iterating over the return value.

---

The full forms of the `testlist_safe` and `old_test` definitions are

```
testlist_safe: old_test [(',' old_test)+ [',']]
old_test: or_test | old_lambdef
```

`testlist_safe` isn't always a single `old_test`, and `old_test` isn't always an `old_lambdef`. It's permitted for `testlist_safe` to be an `old_test`, and it's permitted for `old_test` to be an `old_lambdef`. Doing those things together always produces an exception at runtime, but they weren't going to complicate the grammar just to stop people from doing those things together.

Comment: @Ivan: Nope. An expression of this structure will always produce a TypeError. You're probably thinking "then why is it even permitted", but it would be a lot more work to forbid it, for no real benefit.

Comment: @anyone else reading: the production rules in the question are not the entire definitions of these nonterminals, or even the entire forms of those productions. Also, these aren't the only uses of these nonterminals. It might look like some of these productions have no reason to exist, but that's only because the full context isn't visible here.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could explain in simple words why such a grammar construct will always produce a TypeError?

Comment: @Ivan: An `old_lambdef` always evaluates to a function object, which isn't iterable, but the code structure you've specified will always try to iterate over it.

Comment: But in the example provided with the question `old_lamddef` evaluates into generator, which is iterable. So `for in lambda: ...` still makes sense. Why TypeError ?

Comment: @Ivan: The example in the question does not use `old_lambdef`. It uses `or_test`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143920/discussion-between-ivan-and-user2357112).